# Intellisense not refreshing resource edits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a reproducible issue with Intellisense when editing resource files.

If I edit resources ( menu entries, through the UI) and let it regenerate the resource header then all files including the header won't pick up the changes until visual studio is restarted.
Closing and reopening the file including the header isn't enough.

If I edit the header manually all changes including ones previously introduced by the resource UI are accounted for.

In either case the compiler has no issues, only the editor does in that it flags the use of header provided defines as an error.

Is this a familiar bug or an unintended consequence of some Intellisense to anybody? It's a minor annoyance, but an annoyance nonetheless.

Comment: Hi, does this issue persists for all your C++ projects? Could you please share a simple solution that we can reproduce this issue, upload to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link? Thanks

Comment: I haven't checked in other projects or solutions as I never had to use resources outside of the project I'm involved with now. I will try and repro a simpler case and share if it occurs.